# Display Object Name from has_and_belongs_to_many join table in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Product` model and a `Tag` model in a `has_and_belongs_to_many`  relationship with a `join_table`. My Tag has one string column called `name`.

Everything works, but on my Product index view, I'd like to list all the Tags associated with the Product.  Since its in a join_table, I am not sure how to create the bridge to get the Tag name; all I seem to be able to do is list all the tag_ids.

**products/index.html.erb**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.tag_ids %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  ...
end
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags should be accessible throug product.

You could simply call `tags` on your `product` instance if I got issue correctly.

```
<% product.tags.map do |tag| %>
    ...
    <%= tag.name %>
    ...
<% end %>
```